# 'Error: list assignment index out of range' for neuronetwork training function

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm working on a backpropagation algorithm, and on the function to train a network with a fixed number of epochs I keep getting the following index error:

```
File "backprop-seed.py", line 149, in train_network
    expected[row[-1]] = 1
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Here's the function:

```
def train_network(network, train, l_rate, n_epoch, n_outputs):
    for epoch in range(n_epoch):
        for row in train:
            outputs = forward_prop(network, row)
            expected = [0 for i in range(n_outputs)]
            expected[row[-1]] = 1
            backprop_err(network, expected)
            update_weights(network, row, l_rate)
```

How should I correct this error?

Comment: either expected or row are empty when you attempt to index the last item by using the -1